# CompareTo is transitive

Tags: java, compare, comparator, compareto

I have  a POJO looking like this:

```
public class Pojo implements Comparable<Pojo> {

    private String type;

    private String journalId;

    private Date bookingDate;

    private Long account;

    private String description;

    private BigDecimal debit;

    private BigDecimal credit;

    ....
}
```

and I want to sort a list of these POJOs. Currently my `compareTo` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(EfdisJournal other) {
    int i = this.type.compareTo(other.type);
    if (i != 0)
        return i;
    if (this.bookingDate != null && other.bookingDate != null)
        i = this.bookingDate.compareTo(other.bookingDate);
    if (i != 0)
        return i;
    if (this.journalId != null && other.journalId != null)
        i = this.journalId.compareTo(other.journalId);
    if (i != 0)
        return i;
    return this.account.compareTo(other.account);
}
```

If I run a sort with this `compareTo` method, I get this `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract` error. I did google a bit and I think it happens because some of the fields are `null` on comparison. Yet I have no idea how to solve this or if I am right why that error appears.

The comparison should work like this: 1st compare by `type`, then compare by `bookingDate`, as 3rd compare by `journalId` and at last compare by `account`. All comparisons should be ascending.

- `type` is never null
- `bookingDate` may be null
- `journalId` may be null
- `account` is never null

---

EDIT:

Sadly I was not able to implement the method, so that the order is as needed. Yet, i solved the problem I had, because the stored procedure yielded 2 resultsets, of which the second was order as needed, so the only thing I had to do was to use the 2nd resultset instead of the first.

Comment: How would you like to order elements based on field which is null?

Comment: You should decide whether things with `null` bookingDate should be sorted _before_ or _after_ things with a non-null bookingDate, and write your `compareTo` appropriately. (And then `journalId` too.) Then you can get an order that sorts consitently.

Comment: if the `bookingdate` is null, then it should compare by `journalId` and if thats null too, then it should compare `account`. i'll update how the result should look like

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The order you are describing is not transitive.

Comment: @khelwood the only thing i found to this error on stackoverflow said, that my compare method would be transitive. I don't even know what exactly that means

Comment: Transtive means that if `A < B` and `B < C` then it always follows that `A < C`. If you have your comparison code ignoring fields sometimes and not others, you can produce a non-transitive (i.e. inconsistent) order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deal with the case where *one* instance has a null `bookingDate`, and the other has a non-null `bookingDate`.
You should decide whether things with null `bookingDate` should be sorted before or after things with a non-null `bookingDate`, and write your compareTo appropriately. (And then `journalId` too.) Then you can get an order that sorts consistently.

For instance:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(EfdisJournal other) {
    int i = this.type.compareTo(other.type);
    if (i != 0) {
        return i;
    }
    if ((this.bookingDate==null) ^ (other.bookingDate==null)) {
        return (this.bookingDate==null ? -1 : 1);
    }
    if (this.bookingDate != null && other.bookingDate != null) {
        i = this.bookingDate.compareTo(other.bookingDate);
    }
    if (i != 0) {
        return i;
    }
    if ((this.journalId==null) ^ (other.journalId==null)) {
        return (this.journalId==null ? -1 : 1);
    }
    if (this.journalId != null && other.journalId != null) {
        i = this.journalId.compareTo(other.journalId);
    }
    if (i != 0) {
        return i;
    }
    return this.account.compareTo(other.account);
}
```

Comment: can you explain what the `^` does?

Comment: `^` is exclusive or: it returns true if one of its operands is true and the other is false.

Comment: ah okay. sadly your solution does not yield the result i am seeking. is it even possible to get a list, which is ordered as the example i posted?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer In the example you posted, the last column is strictly increasing, so I'm not sure why you don't just sort by that.

Comment: in Reality its not strictly increasing. 2 different dates can have the exact same `accounts`

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring situations where `bookingDate` and/or `journalId` is null with one and non-null with the other.